# in the tests, after upgrade to symfony4, every request gets a new session

Tags: symfony, session, symfony4

I want to upgrade from symfony 3.4 to 4.4. But directly after this change, many functional tests are broken. Analyzing shows that for every request, I get a new session id, so also a new session. What do I do wrong?

```
$client = $this->createClient();
$client->request('GET', '/');
dump($client->getReqest()->getSession()->getId());
$client->request('GET', '/');
dump($client->getReqest()->getSession()->getId());
```

shows a different session ID. (In symfony3.4 it is the same.)

Where is the session id saved in tests? Like normally in a cookie? <s>I see no session cookie (in `$client->getRequest()`), only one other cookie.</s> I see the session cookie in `$client->getRequest()->cookies`, and then a different id in `$client->getResponse->headers`.

Did I miss to adapt some config? I use flex before and after the update, so I did not mix it up with this change.
`config/packages/test/framework.yaml` contains `frameworks: session: storage_id: session.storage.mock_file`, which is default from the recipe. The mocked session files are visible in the cache.

Comment: Oops, I had `framework: session: cookie_path` set by mistake in `.env.test.local`. Symfony3 ignored it for tests, symfony4 does not. So trying on...

Comment: The problem does not happen on all instances. I do not yet know what is the difference between them. Some parameters? Different host? php version 7.2.32.x and 7.2.31.x?

Comment: Now the problem is fixed. Something must habe been wrong with one instance, which is fixed now. But no what changed.   Thanks for everybody who thought about the solution. Question: what shall I do now with this? Delete? add an answer?